# Problema con Validación de Formulario

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario de mantenimiento que tiene una tabla donde están listados los registros de una tabla en cada fila de la tabla tengo un radio button de manera que si selecciono algún registro de la tabla me permita eliminar o editar segun el boton (submit) pulsado. la validación en Javascript es la siguiente:

```
function checkSel(Form) {
var frm = document.getElementById(Form);
for (i=0;i<frm.elements.length;i++) { 
    if (frm.elements[i].type == "radio") { 
        if (frm.elements[i].checked) {
            if (confirm("¿Esta seguro de Eliminar el Registro?")) {
                return true;    
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
alert("No selecciono ningun registro, Debe seleccionar un registro para 
efectuar la operación.");
return false;
}
```

La validación funciona bien, pues cuando no selecciono registro me envia el mensaje "No Seleccion ningun......" y cuando selecciono me pregunta si estoy seguro de eliminar el registro, el problema es con el con el Return pues haga lo que haga siempre ejecuta el procedimiento como si la funcion retornara siempre Verdadero. cabe indicar que invoco a la validación de la siguiente manera:

```
onclick="checkSel('FormTab');"
```

he probado también como por ahí me sugirieron de la siguiente forma:

```
onclick="checkSel('FormTab');return false;"
```

de esta manera siempre me retorna falso, osea nunca ejecuta. estoy con esto desde ayer, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta el `return` al invocar la función:

```
onclick="return checkSel('FormTab');"
```

Comment: Eso era me faltaba el return, gracias hermano.